# Function to append a character to the end of a string

Tags: c, string, realloc

From what I've read and understand, for example when we pass a string to a function, inside that function we can't use sizeof( array )/sizeof( array[ 0 ] ) to determine the length of the string. So I was wondering it this function to append a character to the end of a string is correct:

```
void append_ch_to_str( char *str, char ch )
{
    int length = strlen( str );

    str = ( char * )realloc( str, ( length + 1 ) * sizeof( char ) );

    length = strlen( str );

    *( str + length - 1 ) = '\0';
    *( str + length - 2 ) = ch;
}
```

Comment: I think it is not correct.

Comment: (1) The length of the string won't change across the `realloc()`, so the second `strlen()` is superfluous. (2) The length you allocate is too small (off by one). (3) You're writing to the wrong locations with your new update statements. (4) You're not conveying the new location of the allocated memory back to the calling code.  Of these, (1) is least serious; the others are all critical to the correct operation of your code.  NB: `strlen()` counts the number of bytes in the string up to the null byte; this may or may not bear any relation to the amount of space allocated for the string.

Comment: You might also want to think about the potentially quadratic behaviour from calling this function repeatedly. For many purposes, a better interface might be to append a string to the string, with the one character string being a special case. Used occasionally, the current design won't hurt.  Doing a better job of adding one character at a time requires a more complex string type than `char *` or `char **`.

Comment: C is pass by value ... any changes to a parameter (itself; not what a pointer parameter refers to) are lost upon return -- see JL's 4th point.

Answer (score 2):

It is not correct, but may be corrected as follows:

```
char *append_ch_to_str( char *str, char ch )
{
    int length = strlen( str );
    char *str2;

    str2 = ( char * )realloc( str, ( length + 2 ) * sizeof( char ) );
    if (!str2) {
        free(str);
        return NULL;
    }
    str = str2;

    str[length] = ch;
    str[length+1] = 0;

    return str;
}
```

All this is assuming that the `str` pointer is to already allocated memory with `malloc/calloc/strdup`.

Allocation should provide space for terminating `0` character and one more for the added one.

The second calculation of string length will have the same result, because it will count characters that are non-zero, and will not return the size of the allocated buffer.

You have to check for realloc returning `NULL` in case of not enough memory. EDIT: I added checking for realloc return value - this will hopefuly prevent copying the unfinished code...

As pointed in comments this is also a bad approach because realloc is not guaranteed to return the same pointer value, that is why the function will return the new pointer value and the original one will no longer be valid after its execution.

Comment: Right, realloc may not return the same pointer. I will fix it.

Comment: `x=realloc(x,...)` is an anti-pattern. If realloc returns NULL, you've leaked the memory `x` used to point at. (I know you say that the return value needs to be checked, but you should show it, too; otherwise, copy-and-pasters will do so.)

Comment: Fully agree. Corrected that too

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have a memory leak as `realloc` may return a different pointer that str, which that you throw awary.

Also due to this the new string is not passed back to the caller.

Comment: But isn't the string passed by ference?

Comment: @FernandoKarpinski- no - you need to pass char **

Comment: @FernandoKarpinski Nothing is passed by reference in C ... all parameters are passed by value.